# Embed command line inside window?

Tags: c++, command-line

Is it possible to embed system command line right inside your application window?

I want to be able to have the command line take some space on the bottom of my C++ application, and my application to take the above space. Ideally it should work on Mac, Linux and Windows, but for starters Windows is the primary goal as I am developing on it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'take some space'? Do you want to display the command line on your window? Or do you want to embed it in the executable? If you want to embed it in the executable, which command-line shall it be? The last invocation?

Comment: I want to display the command line inside the window, and move along inside the window when the user moves my window. I want it to function as normal, so it's just embedded there. Either embed the executable, or somehow render/put the system cmd in there virtually.

Comment: Seeing tenfours answer, is it a GUI application or a console application??

Comment: It's a GUI application. To be precise, I have Chromium embedded and I want to render a website above and a terminal below in a single window.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, you can do that using some WinAPI functions like `ShellExecute` and `CreateProcess` (there are a few others that I don't remember). You get the command string from your GUI, pass it to one of these WinAPI functions, then send the output back to your GUI.

You want to do this on multiple platforms, so I would suggest making a generic module (class or namespace of functions, whatever fits you best) that allows using the OS terminal agnostic of the actual underling OS. Then. when you want to port your app to another OS, you just change the implementation of this module.

Note: Boost has (had?) a library under development that made running shell commands easier, [Boost.Process](http://www.highscore.de/boost/process/). But it's currently on version 0.4 and hasn't been updated since October 4, 2010 (even though its status is still "on going").

Comment: Can this work so that interactive command line works as well? For example, think about Linux `less` or Git's `log` command, they have interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking for Windows, the Windows console window is "special" in that it gets special treatment, different than any other window on the system. You will not succeed in manipulating it for your own use. For a good example, try using Spy++ on a console window.

Note that the window created with `AllocConsole` is not a command-line interpreter, it's just a console window.

You should implement your own console window, and as far as interpreting the commands I can think of a few options to explore depending on what you expect, behavior-wise and complexity-wise:

1. Delegate commands to a hidden cmd.exe
2. Interpret commands yourself
3. There are probably open-source solutions for command line interpreting.

Comment: Can the delegation work so that interactive command line works as well. For example, think about Linux `less` or Git's `log` command, they have interaction.

Comment: Yes, it takes a bit of work though. The child process (`less` / etc) uses the standard input handles `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`. You will need to deal with these handles using console I/O redirection, by passing your own handles to `CreateProcess`. There are lots of articles on this and questions here on SO. Here's one: http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm